# Self References

Tags: database-normalization, self-referencing-table

For an assessment task I'm doing, an entity album has the attribute also_bought, which is a self-referential attribute. However, this one attribute has multiple entries for any one album - as the also_bought recommendations are rarely only one recommendation - and thus, is a bit of a question mark when it comes to normalisation. I'm not sure whether it passes 1NF or not.

To be clear, the entire entity's set is

Album(album_id, title, playtime, genre, release_date, price, also_bought)

Comment: What definition of "1NF" do you mean? (See link in my answer.) What does "multiple entries" mean? That also_bought values are lists of album_ids? What exactly are the types of your columns?

Answer (score 0):

"Also bought" items should be stored in a separate table, something like.

```
AlsoBought (table)
  album_id
  also_bought_album_id
```

Then configure foreign keys from both columns to reference Album.album_id.

Answer (score 0):

You mean that *Album* is a "self-referencing *table*" because it has a FK (foreign key) from one column list to another in the same table? (A FK constraint holds when subrow values for a column list must appear elsewhere.) If you mean that the type of also_bought is a list of album_ids, there is no FK from the former to the latter, because values for the former (lists of ids) are not values for the latter (ids). There's a constraint that is reminding you of a FK.

Anyway, normalization is done to one table, and doesn't depend on FKs.

But any time you are ["normalizing to 1NF" eliminating "non-atomic columns"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40640962/3404097) you have to start by deciding what your "table" "columns" contain. If you decide a cell for a column in a row contains "many values" then you don't have a relational table and you have to come up with one. The easiest way is to assume a set-valued column to get a relation and then follow the [standard rules for elimination of too-complex column types](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37483508/3404097).