# Should I break the atomicity rule storing a list of items when there is no reason to query about items?

Tags: database-schema, database-normalization, multivalue

The same item may belong to multiple lists, and each list has many items.

The "proper" design: Make a join table, which has list_ID and item_ID. When I want all the items in a list, query for list_ID.

Design that breaks the atomicity rule: Make a list table. Primary Key, and either repeating columns or non-atomic columns. These deviations suffer as drawback the inability to efficiently query on items.

Normalizing a database to 1NF makes sure each column is atomic, so I should NOT do option B. That would make querying items hard. E.g. "how many of this item got sold?" or "how many times is this item in a list?"

I will never need that data. Should I break the atomicity rule storing a list of items when there is no reason to query about items? Verses a join table that requires a whole join table be scanned.

Is that already a mistake? Is there a meme like "you'll always want to be able to query, and you won't have time to reorganize the database when you scale"? Am I overestimating how long it wouldd take MySQL to scan a join table?

It's common sense to accept that non-compliant form if I know that the drawback is not important to the application.

Answer (score 1):

**TL; DR** If you are going to write generic query/constraint expressions about parts of values of a column then the parts ought to get their own columns; otherwise not. If you change your mind then you can supply the old schema via a view, although typically updates would need recoding.

---

Relations have rows that have for each column one value of that column's type. Notions of "relation" or "normalized" or "1NF" in terms of some notion of ["atomicity"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24038895/3404097) are vague, confused and unhelpful. Eg a list is typically called "non-atomic", while a string is called "atomic"--even though a string is a list of characters. Bite the bullet--it's nonsense.

*Every single design* has to make this where-the-turtles-stop decision about its [column types](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37483508/3404097). It cannot be avoided. (Even when you get to a bit-typed column, you can decide to have a separate table for only the rows that would have 1s.) (Then there is no column hence no column type.) It is a design quality issue, but not an issue of normalization to higher NFs (normal forms).

Nothing in "normalization" to higher NFs (reducing certain update/redundancy problems by replacing a table by tables that join back to it) requires prior application-dependent ["normalization" to "1NF" per "atomicity"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40640962/3404097) (replacing a table by some table(s) with columns for parts of its columns). Because when rearranging to "1NF" would *help* we would need to write constraint expressions involving parts of values of columns so we would be doing that rearrangement *anyway*.

(Unfortunately "normalized" & "1NF" & "0NF" get used in many different ways, many nonsensical although common. Better to just say what exact property/properties you mean.)

---

PS 1 A list is generally considered to be an ordered collection of items, a set being an unordered collection of items. Predicate "collection *C* has item *I* as *Nth* member" records a list, "collection *C* has item *I* as a member" a set.

PS 2 PS Your presumption that a representation of a list or set "vertically" or "compactly" "down" a column in a table involves any more "scanning" than a representation "horizontally" or "compactly" "across" a value in a column in a row is naive/unjustified. Ie ((list, item1, 1), (list, item2, 2), ...) vs (list, [item1, item2, ...]).