# One-to-many relationship: composite primary key or single primary key?

Tags: database, database-design, relational-database

I have a table `person` containing personal info, and I have another table `person_contact` to store contact information about that person (`type` shows if it's a phone record or email record, and `record` contains the actual phone number or email address).

I have designed the schema like this: 
[image]

In `person_contact` I have declared `pcont_id` and `person_id` as PK while `person_id` is a FK referencing `person.person_id`. Do I need the PK `pcont_id` at all? When should I use a single PK in a one-to-many relationship and when is it better to use composite PK?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Composite Primary Keys : is it good or bad](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26078535/composite-primary-keys-is-it-good-or-bad)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need `person_id` as a part of your primary key in `person_contact` table. `pcont_id` should be the primary key if you have a one to many relationship between the two tables.

> Do I need the PK pcont_id at all?

I suggest, it should be there and should be primary key of your table assuming you can have multiple contacts for one person.

If one person can have only one contact, in that case you don't need that table itself, you can store the data directly in the person table.

If you still want to store it separately then you don't need `pcont_id` column, your `person_id` column should be marked as primary key.

> When should I use a single PK in a one-to-many relationship and when
>   is it better to use composite PK?

Composite primary key is used when you have a `junction table/associative table` to map a many-to-many relationship. In case of one-to-many relationship you don't need composite primary key with the foreign key column.