# Problem of matching unique or primary key for this column-list

Tags: sql, oracle

I have work to do in SQL, and I have a problem about the referencing of a key. So I have two tables:

```
CREATE TABLE Surveillances
(
    NumEns NUMERIC(10) REFERENCES Enseignants,
    DateHeureDebut TIMESTAMP(0),
    NumSal NUMERIC(4) REFERENCES Salles,
    PRIMARY KEY(NumEns, DateHeureDebut)
);
```

```
CREATE TABLE Horaires
(
    NumEpr NUMERIC(10) REFERENCES Epreuves,
    DateHeureDebut TIMESTAMP(0) REFERENCES Surveillances,
    PRIMARY KEY(NumEpr)
);
```

I already created the table `Surveillances`, but when I try to create the table `Horaires`, this error appears

> Error report -
>
> ORA-02270: no matching unique or primary key for this column-list.

I find out that the problem comes from the key `DateHeureDebut` which is a primary key in the table `Surveillances`, but not in `Horaires`.

I tried to modify my `Horaires` table, but that didn't work:

```
CREATE TABLE Horaires
(
    NumEpr NUMERIC(10) REFERENCES Epreuves,
    DateHeureDebut TIMESTAMP(0),
    PRIMARY KEY(NumEpr),
    FOREIGN KEY(DateHeureDebut) FROM Surveillances(DateHeureDebut)
);
```

I just tried this :

```
CREATE TABLE Horaires
(
    NumEpr NUMERIC(10) REFERENCES Epreuves,
    DateHeureDebut TIMESTAMP(0),
    NumEns NUMERIC(10),
    PRIMARY KEY(NumEpr),
    FOREIGN KEY(NumEns, DateHeureDebut) REFERENCES Surveillances(NumEns, DateHeureDebut)
);
```

And it works, I mean no error, but in the `Horaires` table there is no `NumEns` key.

I have to follow this schema :

[image]

The underline words are primary key

Comment: A foreign key must reference a key in the other table (the whole key). Either the primary key, or a unique constraint.

Comment: Yes, but in this case, **DateHeureDebut** from **Horaires** references to the primary key **DateHeureDebut** from **Surveillances**, no ? So why it tells me that they are not matching ?

Comment: `DateHeureDebut` is **not** a primary key in `Surveillances`, it is **part of** the primary key (which consists of `NumEns` **and** `DateHeureDebut`). The foreign key constraint has to reference the entire key, not just part of the key.

Comment: Ok, I think I understand what you meant, is this correct : ```FOREIGN KEY(DateHeureDebut) REFERENCES Surveillances(NumEns, DateHeureDebut)```

Comment: No, you need two columns to reference that primary key.

Comment: Ok, I just add a column `NumEns` in my `Horaires` table, the referencing work, but the table `Horaires` does not contain the key `NumEns`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To reference a composite primary key you need to match all the columns. Example:

```
create table table_a (
    num1_n                         number not null,
    num2_n                         number not null,
    PRIMARY KEY(num1_n, num2_n)
)
;


create table table_b (
    table_b_id                     number generated by default on null as identity 
                                   constraint table_b_table_b_id_pk primary key,
    num1_n                         number not null,
    num2_n                         number not null,
    FOREIGN KEY(num1_n, num2_n) 
      REFERENCES table_a(num1_n, num2_n)
)
;
```

However, the question is - *why* are you using a composite primary key ? Is it really needed ? It would be a lot easier to use a *simple* primary key column with no other functionality than primary key and create a unique index on the columns for which the combination is unique. That is just a lot easier to work with. The above example would then be

```
create table table_a (
    table_a_id                     number generated by default on null as identity 
                                   constraint table_a_table_a_id_pk primary key,
    num1_n                         number not null,
    num2_n                         number not null
)
;

create unique index table_a_u1 ON table_a(num1_n,num2_n);

create table table_b (
    table_b_id                     number generated by default on null as identity 
                                   constraint table_b_table_b_id_pk primary key,
    table_a_id                     number
                                   constraint table_b_table_a_id_fk
                                   references table_a
);
```

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26078535/composite-primary-keys-is-it-good-or-bad) is a good SO post on why to use (or not use) composite primary keys.

Comment: I don't know actually why I'm using a composite primary key, by the way I just learned about what is a composite primary key. But I have a schema which show us the structure of the project, I add it in the question

Comment: My answer already has an example of how to reference a composite primary key - you should be able to figure out the syntax for your project.

Answer (score 0):

I see that you have accepted the other answer. So maybe you don't need any more help on this. After all, your request is not only about how to technically introduce a foreign key constraint in the database, but on where to use them to guarantee data consistency. If you don't need help here, imply ignore this post :-)

I am not even able yet to give a complete answer. But what I have to say is much too long for a comment...

Your data model is about exams (`epreuves`). An exam can take place in several rooms (`salles`) and this relation is stored in the table `occupations`. An exam takes place at a certain date/time. Instead of simply storing the date/time in the exams table, you have created a separate table `horaires` for this on the same key (the exam number). The data model would be simpler, did you store the date/time in the exams table `epreuves` and drop the schedule table `horaires`.

Let's look at three sample exams, "MATH 1" and "PHYSICS 2" and "ARTS 4", all taking place on October 27, 2021. "MATH 1" takes place at 10:00 am in rooms 1 and 2, and "PHYSICS 2" at 10:00 pm in rooms 2 and 3, and "ARTS 4" takes place at 3:00 pm in rooms 2 and 3. That means that at 10 am in room 2 there are students of math and physics exams, probably placed such that a math student sits next to a physics student, so they cannot copy their neighbor's results :-)

Now there is another table "surveillances" saying which teacher (`enseignants`) is in which room on the exam date/times. This table allows more than one teacher per room and date/time. Maybe for instance a math teacher and a physics teacher both at 10 am in room 2. (I *suppose* this is only about exam date/times, not about regular classes, but I may be wrong.)

The problem with this: You want the tables to match. There must not be an exam in a room without a surveillance teacher (and a surveillance without an exam taking place may also be not desired).

Now, first of all, please confirm that my explanation matches what you want your data model to represent. I will then give you my opinion on how to go about constraints there.